# Could not load file or assembly 'Glimpse.AspNet' or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, glimpse

I have just tried to install Glimpse.MVC5 via Nuget.
After doing that I cannot run my application. 
The error says that the assembly Glimpse.AspNet cannot be loaded, but I found that the dll at C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\yyy\zzz\packages\Glimpse.AspNet.1.8.0\lib\net45\Glimpse.AspNet.dll does exist. 
The error in full is;

Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'Glimpse.AspNet' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Glimpse.AspNet' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Glimpse.AspNet' could not be loaded.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Glimpse.AspNet
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: Glimpse.AspNet | Domain ID: 2
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/yyy/zzz/zzz.yzyzyz/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\yyy\zzz\zzz.yzyzyz\bin

## Calling assembly : (Unknown).

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\yyy\zzz\zzz.yzyzyz\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\xxx\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/fec53fa6/71c52709/Glimpse.AspNet.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/fec53fa6/71c52709/Glimpse.AspNet/Glimpse.AspNet.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/yyy/zzz/zzz.yzyzyz/bin/Glimpse.AspNet.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/yyy/zzz/zzz.yzyzyz/bin/Glimpse.AspNet/Glimpse.AspNet.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/fec53fa6/71c52709/Glimpse.AspNet.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/fec53fa6/71c52709/Glimpse.AspNet/Glimpse.AspNet.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/yyy/zzz/zzz.yzyzyz/bin/Glimpse.AspNet.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/yyy/zzz/zzz.yzyzyz/bin/Glimpse.AspNet/Glimpse.AspNet.EXE.

Stack Trace:

[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Glimpse.AspNet' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +70
   System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +39
   System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +37
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +65
   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Glimpse.AspNet' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +348
   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, Boolean checkAptcaBit) +19
   System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry.SecureGetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +39
   System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry..ctor(String name, String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +42
   System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1 moduleList) +158
   System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext) +950
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +82
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Glimpse.AspNet' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9931916
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34248

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the problem was.
After I created a new project to my application, the project I loaded Glimpse into was not building, and that is why there was a problem. When I build the project individually it works. I need to sort out my builds

Comment: I'm glad you tracked it down.